# Sending email: asp.net mvc4

Tags: asp.net, email, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to send mails from my application to different recipients as entered by the user.

My model class,

```
public class Mail
 {
    public int MailId { get; set; }

    public string Mail_To { get; set; }

    public string Mail_From { get; set; }

    public string Mail_Subject { get; set; }

    public string Mail_Contents { get; set; }

    public DateTime Mail_Date { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Anganwadi")]
    public int AnganwadiId { get; set; }
    public virtual Anganwadi Anganwadi { get; set; }
}
```

My controller looks like,

```
[HttpPost]
    public ViewResult SendMail(Mail mail) 
    {
        try
        {
if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                mail.Mail_Date = System.DateTime.Now;
                mail.AnganwadiId = 1;
                mail.Mail_From = "k@gmail.com";
                mail.Mail_Subject = "From Anganwadi";
                MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
                message.From = new MailAddress(mail.Mail_From);
                message.To.Add(new MailAddress("v@gmail.com"));
                message.Subject = mail.Mail_Subject;
                message.Body = mail.Mail_Contents;

                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
                client.Send(message);
                return View("Thanks", mail);
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return View(e);
        }
    }
```

In my web config i added following

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp from="test@foo.com">
      <network host="smtp.efernssolutions.com" port="587" defaultCredentials="true" />
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Gets an error

```
Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: authsmtp12: Host 117.196.165.214: No unauthenticated relaying permitted
```

Am not sure this is correct way. please help me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You have `from="test@foo.com"` in smtp configuration and it's used instead of address from your code. 
This email has invalid MX record in it's domain (http://www.digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=foo.com%0D%0A&type=ANY&useresolver=8.8.4.4&ns=auth&nameservers=)

You should better use existed emails even for testing.

Comment: Still no luck..I tried giving real email. Now error is, "Unable to connect to the remote server"

Comment: Then check credentials you are using to access smtp server